# Sending yourself a copy of the email

Tags: 7, webforms

[image]

I m using Drupal 7 with the Webform module to send email. On a form I have checkbox to send yourself an email copy. When it is checked, there will be a field to enter the email of who sends the email. The email should be send to this address also.

Comment: Hello, Please share whatever you have worked on this and what issue you have found.

Comment: I ve create a web form to send mail to website admin and it has some fields like name, sender mail,body and i ve check box whether to send this webform content to your mail address,if the user checked on it and submit it the content should sent to both user and the admin

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom module for this functionality. This module file used for creating a send a copy of message to me functionality

```
function sendmail_webform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);   
     // webform_client_form_52  webform id
     if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_52') {     
         $form['submitted']['send_a_mail_yourself'] = array(
         '#type' => checkbox,
         '#form_key' => 'send_a_mail_yourself',
         '#title'=> 'Send a copy of yourself',
         '#weight' => 4, // As your needed
         '#field_prefix' => '<div id=\'send_a_mail_yourself\'>',
         '#field_suffix' => '</div>',
         '#default_value' => array('yes' => t('send a copy of yourself')),
       );
       $form['#submit'][] = '_sendmail_webform_submit';

       }
     }

   function _sendmail_webform_submit($form, &$form_state) {        
     $param = array();
     foreach($form_state['input']['submitted'] as $key => $values) {
        if(valid_email_address($values)) {
             $to = $values; //to email address
        }
        else if($key == 'send_a_mail_yourself' && $values == 1) {                    
              $send_a_mail = $values;  // Check send a mail to yourself checkbox

        } else {
          if($values) {
               $param[]  = $values;  // All remaining values to store to param array for use of email body
          }
        }            
       } 

          if($send_a_mail == 1) {                  
         $from = 'noreply@example.com';
                 foreach($param as $param_values) {
            $body[] = $param_values;
           }

        $to = $to; // Set this email address - emails will be sent to this email address!
        $params = array(
            'body' => $body,
            'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
     );
        if (drupal_mail('sendmail_webform', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE)) {
            drupal_set_message('Thanks, we will be in contact with more information soon.');
     } else {
            drupal_set_message('There was an error subscribing you. Please try again later');
        }

    }      
  }

 function sendmail_webform_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
     $headers = array(
         'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
         'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;',
         'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
         'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
    );
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
         $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
    }
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'] = $params['body'];
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two types -  Custom and Component, if You select custom you can write your own like: test@gmail.com. For Component - the submitted form field value will send email. For your requirement simply add another email custom : admin@example.com